# Spring Boot JdbcTemplate Unable to determine the correct call signature - multiple procedures/functions/signatures

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have a Spring Boot application that uses JdbcTemplate to call a stored procedure named **up_RefData_getParticipantBitCrossINTERN**

When the application calls the stored procedure, the following exception is thrown:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature - **multiple procedures/functions/signatures** for **'up_RefData_getParticipantBitCrossINTERN'**: found [**aquadev2**.null.up_RefData_getParticipantBitCrossINTERN, **aquaprod**.null.up_RefData_getParticipantBitCrossINTERN]

My database is MySql 5.x.x and it contains two catalogs **(aquadev2 and aquaprod)** that both contain the same stored procedure.

The JdbcTemplate should not even know about the aquaprod catalog since I specifically stated which catalog to connect to in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/aquadev2?serverTimezone=America/New_York
```

If I hard code which catalog I want in the java code:

```
SimpleJdbcCall getBitCrossInternal = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withProcedureName(STORED_PROC_INTERN).withCatalogName("aquadev2");
```

It works fine, but this is unacceptable to hard code the catalog name .

Why doesn't the JdbcTemplate recognize the catalog name in the datasource URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never received an answer on why I must specify "catalog" but I did manage to avoid hard coding it and settling for having to specify the catalog in application.properties.

in application.properties:

```
refdataserver.datasource.catalog=${DB}
```

Create a class called Datasource in package com.XXX.refdataserver
Make sure you have getter and setter for catalog and @ConfigurationProperties annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "refdataserver.datasource")
@Validated
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Datasource {
   /**
    * Must specify the database in applicaton.properties
    */
   @NotNull(message = "refdataserver.datasource.catalog is mandatory")
   private String catalog;
}
```

Create a properties holder Configuration with an instance of Datasource

```
@Component("serverProps")
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "refdataserver")
@Validated
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class RefDataServerProperties {
   /** refdataserver.datasource properties */
   private Datasource dataSource;
}
```

Then, in any class via autowire, you can retrieve the catalog via the properties configuration.

```
@Autowired
private RefDataServerProperties serverProps;
...
serverProps.getDataSource().getCatalog()
```